# Karyon health check handler not updating Eureka Server

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix

I have a healthcheck handler which checks the status of my application. However my application does not update the status of the app to Eureka. Eureka always shows the app as UP.

I have set:

```
com.netflix.karyon.unify.health.check.with.eureka=true
com.netflix.karyon.health.check.handler.classname=com.test.testcsf.simplesidecar.SimpleSidecarHealthCheckHandler
com.netflix.karyon.server.base.packages=com.test.testcsf.simplesidecar
```

My `SimpleSidecarHealthCheckHandler` code is:

```
import com.netflix.karyon.spi.HealthCheckHandler;

public class SimpleSidecarHealthCheckHandler implements HealthCheckHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSidecarHealthCheckHandler.class);

    /** */
    @Inject
    CheckManager checkManager; 

    @Override
    public int getStatus() {
        logger.debug("health check being called");

        boolean passing = checkManager.allHealthChecksPassing();
        return passing ? 200 : 503;
    }
}
```

checkManager is a class which keeps track of whether the service is down or not. When I print logs, I see that this function is not being called at all. Could someone guide me on what setting should I change ?